# I18n error messages in .NET

Tags: .net, internationalization

I have a .NET application that talks to the AD in order to allow the user to change the password of the AD account. It is a web application used internationally and I can't assume that the user speaks English.

So I need to translate error messages like *"Password does not meet the password policy requirements"* into whatever culture the user sends to the webserver.

- Can I use any internal translation tables or do I manually have to translate the messages via the returned error codes using my own translation tables?
- Is there any way to install all possible resource files for all supported cultures on that server - so that `new Win32Exception(errorcode).Message` will result in the right message?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom error page that your site is redirected to the page you've created:

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="http://hostName/applicationName/errorStatus.aspx" mode="On">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="filenotfound.htm" />
</customErrors>
```

In your errorStatus.htm you can use .NET's globalization features to localize your error message to the appropriate language and culture.

Comment: Hmm, I guess I haven't made myself clear enough. It is not about general error handling in ASP.NET type scenarios. I was asking about printing the polish equivalent of "Password does not meet the password policy requirements" even on a server that has a regular Win2003 EN installed. Wouldn't it be the case that the .NET Framework would still default to English?

Comment: .NET uses two properties for localization:
CurrentUICulture & CurrentCulture

If you have the appropriate resource files in place .NET will automatically localize to these values. If the application is WinForms this is determined by the culture settings of the O/S if its a WebForm app this is determined by the culture settings set in the browser's options.

If you need more info please provide a bit more information regarding the context of the application and I'll see if I can help more